# Windows 7 - Lock Computer/Prevent another user from logging in

Tags: windows-7

How do you prevent a user from logging into Windows 7 when another user has locked the computer?

Answer (score 5):

Open **gpedit.msc** from either the **Run** prompt or from the **Search** box.

Under **Local Computer Policy**, go to **Computer Configuration** -> **Administrative Templates** -> **System** -> **Logon**

[image]

Select the entry that says: **Hide entry points for Fast User Switching**

[image]

Open that entry and select **Enabled** to not allow other users to log on while the computer is locked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disable user switching. Possible on domain computers and maybe others. see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Switch-users-without-logging-off)

> Click the Start button , type gpedit.msc in the search box, and then press Enter.   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>   Under Computer Configuration, click the arrow next to Administrative Templates, and then click the arrow next to System.
>   Click the Logon folder.
>   Double-click Hide entry points for Fast User Switching Properties, click Enabled, and then click OK.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable something known as `Fast User Switching`. I could have sworn that this was possible in the GUI, but I can't seem to find the option anywhere.

It can still be done from Group Policy editor in `Professional` / `Enterprise` / `Ultimate` editions (not sure about others).

You can do it by:

1. Press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> .
2. Type `gpedit.msc`.
3. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy` > `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `System` > `Logon`.
4. Then open `Set Hide entry points for Fast User Switching`.
5. Set this to Enabled.
6. Reboot your machine.

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

just make the user a member of "Power Users" group instead of "Administrators" group

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this works for you (it did for me):
http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-switch-user-option-in-windows-vista-and-7/

Not sure if there is a way around it but the button does not appear.